# Получить дату из замусоренной строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

К примеру есть замусоренная строка: `69qw15_2223фупянваря    2021 года  222023`
Понятно что тут не угадать какой день, но пусть будут 2 рядом стоящие цифры (если есть) перед месяцем. Т.е. день может быть 1, 2, 08, 22 и т.д.

```
.*([0-3]?[0-9]{1}).*(января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря){1}.*?(20[0-9]?[0-9]?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aYzQiE/1
Но в таком случае не вытягивается первая цифра дня. Результат:

```
группа 1    3
группа 2    января
группа 3    2021
```

Как записать первую группу так, чтобы все же получить в данном случае 23 день?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, существующий формат данных разрешает дни месяца 0, 32..39, и его следует исправить: `(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])`

Во-вторых, "жадный" префикс `.*` проглотит все символы до цифры, включая и опциональную первую цифру `[0-3]?`, причём сделает это не слишком эффективно.

Для поиска ближайшей корректной даты перед названием месяца нужно применить конструкцию, включающую негативный lookahead: `ДАТА(Не-ДАТА)*МЕСЯЦ`, тогда полное регулярное выражение выглядит так:

```
(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])(?:(?!0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]).)*(января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря).*?(20[0-9]?[0-9]?)
```

[Онлайн-демо](https://regex101.com/r/aYzQiE/3):

69qw15_**03**фуп**января**    **2021** года 222023

```
Match information  
Match 1 7-26    03фупянваря    2021  
Group 1 7-9     03  
Group 2 12-18   января  
Group 3 22-26   2021
```

---

Однако, в случае дублированного названия месяца данная регулярка выбирает название *последнего* подходящего месяца.  Поэтому может понадобиться внести условие `(?:(?!ДАТА|МЕСЯЦ).)*`, чтобы выбирался *первый* месяц:
[Онлайн-демо](https://regex101.com/r/aYzQiE/4)

69qw15_**03**фуп**января**  марта  **2021** года 222023

```
Match information  
Match 1 7-31    03фупянваря  марта  2021
Group 1 7-9     03  
Group 2 12-18   января  
Group 3 22-26   2021
```

Comment: непонятно только зачем квантификатор {1} после месяцев

Comment: осталось от первоначальной регулярки